# Android Cipher throwing BadPaddingException, but not in Java

Tags: android, encryption

I'm using some basic encryption in my app, which is running Android v20 (4.4.4)

This used to work, but I think with the newer version of Android I'm running, there is now an error throwing the following exception:

```
10-28 12:42:02.312    5173-5332/com.app W/System.err﹕ javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted
10-28 12:42:02.312    5173-5332/com.app W/System.err﹕ at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(BaseBlockCipher.java:739)
10-28 12:42:02.322    5173-5332/com.app W/System.err﹕ at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1204)
10-28 12:42:02.322    5173-5332/com.app W/System.err﹕ at com.app.utils.CryptoClass.decrypt(CryptoClass.java:47)
10-28 12:42:02.322    5173-5332/com.app W/System.err﹕ at com.app.utils.CryptoClass.decrypt(CryptoClass.java:30)
```

The method throwing this is here:

```
private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] rawKey, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec spec = new SecretKeySpec(rawKey, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, spec);

    return cipher.doFinal(encrypted); //THIS LINE THROWS EXCEPTION
}
```

When I run this same code as a Java project, it works correctly (using the same version of Java, 1.7 as Android is using).

I've tried various combinations for the getInstance parameter based on what I've found online, like `AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING` but that doesn't solve the problem.

The getRawKey method I'm using:

```
private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] bytes) throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SECRET");

    secureRandom.setSeed(bytes);
    keygen.init(128, secureRandom);

    SecretKey secretKey = keygen.generateKey();
    return secretKey.getEncoded();
}
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you use the infamous `getRawKey` function that tries to regenerate an AES key using a seed and a *random number generator*?

Comment: Uh... yes. I copied the method from a blogpost which is the first result when you search for how to do it. I actually was about to update this answer, I got it to work but had to re-encrypt the encrypted key I was attempted to decrypt when this problem arose. Is the method I'm using going to make this a problem that continues to occur? I'll add the method getRawKey to the question for reference.

Comment: Note that `Cipher.getInstance("AES")` uses the providers default mode of operation and padding mode. Mostly that means ECB mode of operation and PKCS#7 compatible padding. PKCS#7 padding is fine (unless padding oracle attacks apply). ECB is not, use either CBC or - if available - GCM mode encryption.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of using `SecureRandom` to derive keys is that:

- `SecureRandom` uses an undefined algorithm, which may change between implementations (even from the same vendor).
- the fact that `SecureRandom` *only* uses the given seed as entropy is flawed, this may (and does) change for different implementations.

Above is even true if you specify `"SHA1PRNG"`, which is not a well defined or standardized algorithm. It is not even specified in the JCA as a required algorithm so it may be missing from runtimes (this would break so much code that this is unlikely to be the case though).

In Android, the proprietary functionality of `SecureRandom` in the Oracle provider - and the providers that tried to stay compatible  - was changed in favor of the OpenSSL related provider. This happened from 4.2 onwards. In OpenSSL, `SecureRandom` only mixes the given seed into the entropy pool. In other words, you get a fully random key even if you use the same "password" as seed.

So if you ever see `getRawKey` as defined as above, please try and take it down. And for your own implementations just use `SecretKeySpec` for keys or PBKDF2 for passwords.