# AesEncryption cause different result in Java And PHP code,Why?

Tags: java, php, cryptography, aes, phpseclib

I am connecting a third party interface and they only gave me a Java code demo, I need to connect it with my PHP system.But I can't handle the encryption, my encryption proccess in PHP always gets different result with the third party Java code.

I install phpseclib/phpseclib package via composer in order to perform AES encryption.

Java Encryption Code:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
private static final String KEY_ALGORITHM = "AES";
private static final String DEFAULT_CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding";

public static String encrypt(String content, String encryptKey) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(DEFAULT_CIPHER_ALGORITHM);

            byte[] byteContent = content.getBytes("utf-8");

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(encryptKey));
            byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(byteContent);


            return toHexString(result);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        return null;
    }  

private static SecretKeySpec getSecretKey(final String encryptKey) {
        KeyGenerator kg = null;

        try {
            kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
            SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            secureRandom.setSeed(encryptKey.getBytes());
            kg.init(128, secureRandom);


            SecretKey secretKey = kg.generateKey();
            return new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), KEY_ALGORITHM);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        }

        return null;
    }

public static String toHexString(byte b[]) {
    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        String plainText = Integer.toHexString(0xff & b[i]);
        if (plainText.length() < 2)
            plainText = "0" + plainText;
        hexString.append(plainText);
    }
    return hexString.toString();
}
```

PHP encryption code:

```
//composer require phpseclib/phpseclib
use phpseclib\Crypt\AES;
function aesEncrypt($message, $key)
{
    $cipher = new AES(AES::MODE_ECB);
    $cipher->setKeyLength(128);
    $cipher->setKey(hex2bin($key));

    $cryptText = $cipher->encrypt($message);

    return bin2hex($cryptText);
}
```

Java Result:

```
before:testStringtestString
key:acccd6fa0caf52a0e5e5fda8bd3ff55a
after:2bbd3011eb084c9494228fe913e6e033aaffb1aa04ef9d0f14614c21fd16af9a
```

PHP Result:

```
before:testStringtestString
key:acccd6fa0caf52a0e5e5fda8bd3ff55a
after:d9a683511cdeb174bf51a285140071a8b38b57c6c6133d1b9425846ae0ec333b
```

Comment: Ah, the return of the `getRawKey` BS, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26637406/589259). Why are you even expecting the same answer if `getSecretKey` is completely missing from the PHP code? What do you expect from `SecureRandom` other than to generate random output?

Comment: I thought maybe phpseclib package will handle the key for me

Comment: It does, it will correctly interpret the bytes you feed to it to be the key, instead of doing some random trap to it as performed in the Java code. It's the Java code that is faulty to the extreme. The SHA1PRNG is not well defined; on specific providers (Android) it will generate a pure random key, and you will lose all data you encrypt with it..

Comment: You mean I should add some function like `SecureRandom` to handle the key before?

Comment: I've amended my comment above, I think that should answer your question. If you want to *play* with crypto further, just hex decode the key on Java.

Comment: Sorry, I've try to decode the key use hex2bin, and just get gibberish. I try hard to understand the meaning of your answer, but I am really cannot get your point. The Java Code Above is just a demo that I cannot modify, what I can do is to modify my PHP code to adjust it.

Comment: Well, have fun implementing the Sun version of SHA1PRNG in that case. Really, I don't know who gave you that example, but you'd better NOT take any more lessons from that crap artist. I've spend hours on end fighting that particular method of key derivation.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I will find a way to fix this proplem.

Comment: The only way to solve it is to step through the source code of SHA1PRNG implementation or look up a good description (it's never been officially described) then replicate it in PHP, otherwise the resulting key differs and your ciphertext will differ. And then you would have a perfect copy in PHP on how **not** to perform encryption. Good luck (yes, I mean that).